# Dockable tabs in Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm creating a document editing tool in electron and I'd really like to split the functional views into dockable windows within the program.  I like the functionality of Atom's dockable windows, and how it remembers where they are on next load.

I'm wondering if there are any component libraries or projects out there which are a barebone example of this working?  I've tried picking apart atom to work out how it works, but I'm not sure if I'm going to be able to cleanly extract their code.

Comment: Did I answer your question or do you need more information?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [chrome-tabs](https://github.com/adamschwartz/chrome-tabs) then all you have to do is display the reset of the content by your active tab.